# Cannot set up localhost https server with restify

Tags: node.js, https, localhost, restify

I'm trying to run a [restify](http://restify.com/) https server on localhost, but I keep getting the "0 NO RESPONSE". I tried to follow all the examples that I found with the keywords related to node, https, localhost,... (all are pretty similar and simple, hardly can make it wrong). Also checked the apps that listening to ports and it's there, but still get "0 NO RESPONSE".

If I remove the https configs on the server code and change the request to http then everything works fine. What possibly went wrong here?

Edit: my code is like this

```
import restify from 'restify';
...
const server = restify.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'key.pem')),
  certificate: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'cert.pem'))
});
...
server.listen(443, function()...);
```

Comment: What you do for setting up https configs for localhost ?

Comment: Basically I generated the key and cert (like this one http://www.i-visionblog.com/2014/10/create-https-tls-ssl-application-with-express-nodejs-in-localhost-openssl.html), reading them with `readFileSync()` and pass to `keys` and `certificate` options in `restify.createServer(config.serverOptions)`, then `server.listen()`...

Comment: the passed in key and cert via `readFileSync()` seem to be Buffers, it's allowed isn't it?